# jquery after ajax complete /done , to call a function, the function will execute more and more times. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been stuck on this issue for about 2 days. My code ([JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/st6zm/2/)) is thus:

```
var foo = function(){
    // The code in here will be execute more and more and more times
    $(element).hover(function() {
        console.log("buggie code run")
    })
}

var sliderShow = $(secondElement).bxSlider({
    onAfterSlide:function(currentSlideNumber) {
        $.ajax("/echo/html/").done(function() {
            foo();
        })
    }
})
```

My problem is the code will run more than once. For example, when you hover over the element it will fire the function once, but second time it will fire twice. The third time it will fire 3 times, and so on. Why is this happening? Am I making a basic logic error, or is this JavaScript doing something?

Comment: It sounds like you keep attaching events to the hover, but it would be helpful to have a functional page to look at, not just the results.

Comment: Do not use jsfiddle if the code is just static and not executable! Please edit your question and move the code inside the question.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Did it for him. I left the Fiddle link in as I didn't want to deviate from the original text too much.

Comment: $.ajax doesn't have a .done() function, think you might be looking for .complete()

Comment: @Cubed: `$.ajax` returns a promise object, which has a `done` method.

Comment: @Felix the more you know hey? haven't used jQuery for a while, looks like I'm in need of a refresher. Cheers.

Comment: @Cubed: Yep, it was introduced in jQuery 1.5...

Answer (score 2):

This means you are registering the event more than once, probably on each load. You should do so only once!

Answer (score 0):

Hovering itself calls the function twice once on entry and once on exit.. try

```
var foo = function(){
    $(element).hover(function() {console.log("IN")},function() {console.log("OUT")});
}
```

But then as ThiefMaster pointed out you are also registering the eventhandler multiple times. In you slider, the second time you will add the event handler again and so on and on.

Look at http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events